# Create a usable hyper link with a batch file and insert it into an email

Tags: batch-file, hyperlink

This may be answered somewhere but everything I have tried fails.
I have a batch file that is used to create a link to a page on a website.  It performs many other functions as well but ends with giving me a text file showing the hyper-link and an image named invitation.png.
I then have to open an email (or word doc etc), paste in the 'invitation.png', right click it, choose add hyper-link, paste in the hyper-link from the text file.  This works but is tedious.
The batch file already creates all the necessary parts but cannot put them together.  Is there a way to get this to output the final product to an email or word doc etc?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the mailto: protocol to generate the email, but that won't give you the attachment. At least it would save a few steps. For example:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set subject=Hi Everyone
rem Use \r for carriage returns (new lines) - replaced later - Use %%21 for !
set body=Hi everyone\rThis is just a test email, hope it's a help.\rClick on this link http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png for our favourite forum\r\rBye%%21

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set subject=!subject: =%%20!
set body=!body: =%%20!
set body=!body:\r=%%0d%%0a!
start mailto:someone@somewhere.com?Subject=%subject%^&body=%body%
```

Answer (score 0):

"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\OUTLOOK.EXE"/c ipm.note /m "someone@microsoft.com&subject=test%20subject&body=test%20body" /a c:\test.txt

This was a suggested answer that friend pointed me towards:
https://stackoverflow.com/...pulated-from-command-line
Many thanks to all the people whose efforts contributed to that posting. It got me at least this far.

The only part that isn't here is the ability to paste the contents of the clipboard into the email body.  .  This would need a change at the current statement where "&body=test%20body"

i have tried various things to use there and so far had no luck  The content of the clipboard i need are an image file (file.png) and trying to insert it only results in the name of the file "file.png" being added to the body.  I am not sure where Windows stores the actual contents of the clipboard at any point in time and possibly it could be added directly from that location.  Or maybe the image could be stored as some kind of variable to be inserted?

This is all I can contribute at this time to my own question and i hope this might be enough to help someone else see the answer.

Comment: Your link is dead. :( --- Also, are you posting this as an answer to the question, or to ask for help with automating the pasting into the email body?